# Why can't Singularity GS correctly display the following markup?

Tags: singularitygs

```
<div class="grid">
  <header>header</header>
  <div>main</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

I defined three grids for three screensizes. The markup contains three elements which get displayed in a different column for each screensize.

**mobile layout**, the main div stays in first column, header and footer get displayed in 2nd column

**tablet layout**, all three elements get overlapped in 2nd column (because margin-right: -100%;), seems to be a bug.

**desktop layout**, the only layout which works, header/footer/main get displayed in fifth column

The grid definition:

```
// grid columns
$grids      : 2;
$grids      : add-grid(6 at 40em);
$grids      : add-grid(12 at 50em);

// grid gutters
$gutters    : .2;
```

The styles:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  @include background-grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1080px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.layout {
  // mobile layout
  @include grid-span(1,2);
  // tablet layout
  @include breakpoint(40em){
    @include grid-span(4,2);
  }
  // desktop layout
  @include breakpoint(50em){
    @include grid-span(8,5);
  }
}

header, 
.grid div,
footer { 
  @extend .layout;
}
```

Does somebody know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Singularity needs to know the location of each column. The second value in `grid-span` is the location which you have set to `2` and `5` forcing columns to start in these locations. You can change that value to `1` if you want things to be placed in the first column.

It also sounds like you are used to floating columns across a page so the one before it effects where the following column is placed. By default Singularity uses a technique called [isolation](http://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret). You can switch to the more traditional float method by writing `$output: float`. Documentation for these output styles can be found here: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Output-Styles#float

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Scott. I was aware or thought I know/knew how the grid-span works but I was not anymore aware of the default output style of singularitygs.

Still haven't really figured out why it does not work with my setup but I'll let the people know when solved. just read the article by snugug/john albins post http://snugug.com/musings/on-responsive-designs-dirty-little-secret and get to know what it is all about isolation/float output styles.

thx anyway so far!